# The word "have" in different contexts

Tags: perfect-aspect, auxiliary-verbs

I have a rather unusual question about English for native speakers.

Recently a friend of mine showed me a book to learn my native language (non-English obviously) and I saw a section about "auxiliary verbs". The author of this book wrote that these verbs lose their original meaning in certain situations and, they are only used to mark the grammatical form. I was surprised by this because for me, as a native user, these verbs still had their original meaning in all showed examples.

I started to wonder if a similar situation exists in English for native speakers. In English we have the word "have" which can be used in several contexts:

- I have (possession) a car.
- I have (possession?) work to do.
- I have (aux verb) never eaten pizza like this before.
- I have (aux verb) been living there since I was born.
- I have (aux verb) broken my leg.

I would like you to answer me by describing your feelings instead of focusing on grammar. When you read the above sentences, does the word "have" mean the same thing to you in each of these cases (possession), or does it lose its meaning?

Comment: Relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356681/why-is-have-englishs-main-perfect-auxiliary

Comment: Thanks for the link! I have seen this but it describes more the origin of the perfect tenses instead of native speakers feeling about it.

Comment: Hi, Mike...the problem is that if you ask for feelings about words, you are asking for opinion, and that would make the question closable for Primarily-Opinion-Based. If you phrase it differently you might get some real answers...

Comment: _Have_ does not mean _possess_ when it is used to form the perfect tense, and I'm sure nobody thinks of it in that way.

Comment: 'I have work to do' is polysemous. "You won't be bored during lockdown, will you?" ... "Oh no, but thank you for asking, Jill. I have work to do, though I might not even get round to it: it's not urgent." (here means 'available', 'work I can be getting on with', so 'availability' ('possession' doesn't really work). ////  But "I can't come out tonight. I have work to do" denotes obligation, not availability.